# I do not know where did it fall

Tags: grammar

I do not know where did it fall

Or

I don't know where it fell.

Or

I don't know where has it fallen

Or

I don't know where it has fallen.

Which one is right or appropriate?

Comment: Of the two additional sentences you've added in your edit, "I don't know where it has fallen" is ok but not "I don't know where has it fallen".

Answer (score 4):

> I do not know where did it fall

is not correct, familiar or idiomatic in any written or spoken variety of English that I've come across.

> I don't know where it fell

is fine and normal.

Comment: Edited the question with more queries